# How to redirect to a page in php soap server

Tags: php, nusoap

I have called a nusoap server function to do some stuff and redirect.

This is how I am calling my nusoap function

```
$client=newnusoap_client($endpoint);
$wrapperdiv = $client->call('testFunction', array('details' => $formname ));
```

In test function I used header tag to redirect

```
header("location:www.google.com");
```

but I am getting an error like

> The requested URL serverpath/http//www.google.com was not found on this server.

Comment: Why would you be redirecting from a SOAP call? A SOAP call is never from an end user that's supposed to directly see the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use with `http://`, its always calling that real server, otherwise it will calling relative paths in your server.

```
header("location:http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Google has changed to `https` a while now, so use that.